# How to add a new property into each list item in a C# list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm a C# novice. I was searching for this without any luck. 
Assume I have a database result converted to a list. Something like the following

```
var schedules = db.Schedules.Where(s => s.RequestId == id).ToList();
```

Now i need to add a new element to this list. Not a list item but a property for each list item existing in the list.

For example in php if its a multidimensional array i can use a foreach to loop through the array and it is simple as `$arrayList['new_key'] = "new_value";`

How can I add a property like that to the above `schedules` list in C#? To be more precise; `Schedule` is a dataset. And the new property is also something i want to fetch from a another property of a different dataset.

Help much appreciated.

Edit:
Now i realized what i really need. I need to make a left outer join to connect both Schedule and the other model. I have oped a new question:
[How to create a simple left outer join in lambda expression in EF ASP.NET MVC5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25441850/how-to-create-a-simple-left-outer-join-in-lambda-expression-in-ef-asp-net-mvc5)

Answer (score 2):

"Schedule" (or whatever object set is returned) needs to have the property added<sup>1</sup>. So either add the property to the object, or create a new object with the original object's properties (plus one more) and select into that. e.g.

```
class Schedule2 : Schedule
{
    public String NewProperty { get; set; }

    public Schedule2(Schedule schedule)
    {
        // assign original properties here from "Schedule". e.g.
        base.RequestId = schedule.RequestId;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
var schedules = db.Schedules
                  .Where(x => x.RequestId == id)
                  .Select(x => new Schedule2(x))
                  .ToList();
```

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Notwithstanding the [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't think it's appropriate in this case.</sub>

Comment: did you means `Schedule2` in `Select()`?

Comment: from where we will be assigning new property value?

Comment: Could do so from within the `.Select` e.g. `.Select(x => new Select2(x) { NewProperty = "Foo" })` (Though OP mentions foreach in their question, so I assume they know how to populate it just not add it ;)

Comment: I will try this. but is there a way to just add a property to a list maybe? something like `list.Add('newproperty',8)` ?

Comment: @guitarlass: In c#, no. It's structured and every object isn't based on a dictionary array (like PHP).

Answer (score 0):

You said that `Schedule` was a dataset.  I assume from this that `Schedule` is an instance of `System.Data.DataSet` with a single table, or of `System.Data.DataTable` directly.

It's very easy to add an extra property to a `DataTable`.  All you have to do ahead of time is create and add a new `DataColumn` to the `Columns` property of the `DataTable`.  Something like this:

```
DataSet ds1 = <whatever method returns the dataset>
DataTable dt1 = ds1.Tables[0];
dt1.Columns.Add("NewCol", typeof(string));
```

You will now be able to use "NewCol" as an indexer on any `DataRow` from `dt1`:

```
dt1.Rows[0]["NewCol"] = "a simple string";
```

Comment: I contemplated the same, but given the context (`db.Table`) I believe OP is using "dataset" generally. They're also referencing a specific property within the `Where` predicate, which also leads me to believe they're a set of objects.