# How to create a simple left outer join in lambda expression in EF ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, lambda

I searched hours and hours for this without any luck. I'm trying to create a lambda expression to fetch data from two tables Schedule and Request. But i'm outputting a bool here. How can i do a proper left outer join to fix this?
this is the best i could come up with

```
ViewBag.RequestList = db.Requests
    .Include(r => r.Department)
    .Select(r => db.Schedules.Any(s => s.RequestId == r.RequestId));
```

but its a bool not a list.

Assume my table models are as follows

```
public class Request{
 public virtual int RequestId { get; set; }
 public virtual string Remarks { get; set; }
}

public class Schedule{
 public virtual int ScheduleId{ get; set; }
 public virtual string Name{ get; set; }
 public virtual Request Request { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to see if each and every request has one or more schedules associated with it or not. so if i could attach schedule object to request and output it as a list then thats all i need. 
But I want to do it using LINQ and lambda expressions and I've seen queries as below;

```
var leftList = (from emp in db.Requests
                join d in db.Schedules
                on emp.RequestId equals d.RequestId into output
                from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                select new { RequestId = emp.RequestId, 
                             name = emp.Department.Name, 
                             route = emp.Route.Name });
```

But that's not what i want, because i have to specify every field i need in `new { RequestId = emp.RequestId, name = emp.Department.Name, route = emp.Route.Name }`

Thanks a lot!

Comment: yes `ScheduleId=j==null?0:j.ScheduleId` will do but, see my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

just list what you want like this:

```
          var leftList =    from emp in db.Requests
                            join d in db.Schedules
                            on emp.RequestId equals d.RequestId into output
                            from j in output.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            select new 
                            { 
                               RequestId = emp.RequestId,
                               name = emp.Department.Name, 
                               route = emp.Route.Name,
                               ScheduleId=j==null?0:j.ScheduleId,
                               SName=j==null?""j.Name,
                            };
```

Comment: As i clearly stated in my question i don't want to specify each and every property inside `select new{}` because my original model class Request has many number of properties. is there a way i could fetch all fields like we use `*` in sql?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no simple way to use `select *` for `LINQ`, you can try this `select new { emp,j}`

Comment: The only way is `select emp` or `select j` or `select {emp,j}`